# "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE" for some websites on Mac when connected to iPhone's Personal Hotspot, but the same websites are accessible on the iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, internet, tethering, cellular-data

I'm connected to the internet via Cellular Data on my iPhone. All websites can be accessed. However, when I connect my Mac to my iPhone's Personal Hotspot, some websites can't be reached.

For example, I am able to access https://support.apple.com/ on my iPhone, but the same website leads to a "`ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`" page on my Mac's Edge browser or a "Safari Can't Find the Server" on my Mac's Safari browser.

Comment: Have you discussed this with your cellular data provider?  Does your cellular connection use public address IPv4, CGNAT IPv4, or IPv6? Or some combination?

Comment: @Gilby Hi! How do I know what public address my cellular connection uses?

Comment: Tools like HE.NET Network Tools can help.  But if you are not a pretty competent network person, it may not help very much.  In my case using Telstra, I had to change Mobile Data Network to use a non-default APN (the default is IPv6 only).  But I was following instruction from a Telstra support group. You will need to diagnose the issue with your provider or a support group.